# The Flutter Daemon failed to start

Tags: flutter, git, dart, visual-studio-code, github

**I was working in VS Code and accidentally rolled back the Flutter repository**, which has caused Flutter to become unusable in my development environment. Now, when I try to use Flutter commands or run Flutter projects, nothing happens. I've tried restarting VS Code and my computer, but the issue persists. What steps can I take to resolve this situation and restore Flutter functionality in my VS Code environment?

> Dart (3.2.5): C:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
> Flutter (3.16.8): C:\flutter\flutter (No device)
> [11:46:14 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat with args ["daemon"]
> [11:46:14 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  in C:\flutter\flutter
> [11:46:14 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code","FLUTTER_ROOT":"C:\flutter\flutter"}}
> [11:46:14 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info]     PID: 72960
> [11:46:14 PM] [General] [Info] Returning cached results for project search
> [11:46:14 PM] [General] [Info] Checking 1 projects for supported platforms
> [11:46:14 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["language-server","--protocol=lsp","--client-id=VS-Code","--client-version=3.85.20240327"]
> [11:46:14 PM] [Analyzer] [Info]     PID: 36332
> [11:46:14 PM] [DevTools] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["devtools","--machine","--allow-embedding"]
> [11:46:14 PM] [DevTools] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code","FLUTTER_ROOT":"C:\flutter\flutter"}}
> [11:46:14 PM] [DevTools] [Info]     PID: 72960
> [11:46:14 PM] [General] [Info] Returning cached results for project search
> [11:46:14 PM] [General] [Info] Activating Flutter extension for Flutter project...
> [11:46:14 PM] [General] [Info] Version last used for Pub is 3.2.5 (3.2.0), current is 3.2.5 (3.2.0)
> [11:46:14 PM] [General] [Info] Found 0 folders requiring "pub get" or "pub upgrade":
> [11:46:14 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> Content-Length: 6599
> [11:46:14 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"initialize","params":{"processId":72960,"clientInfo":{"name":"Visual Studio Code","version":"1.87.2"},"locale":"en","rootPath":"c:\Users\ADULUSMAN\Documents\My Flutter Apps\leadergate-master","rootUri":"file:///C%3A/Users/ADULUSMAN/Documents/My%20Flutter%20Apps/leadergate-master","capabilities":{"workspace":{"applyEdit":true,"workspaceEdit":{"documentChanges":true,"resourceOperations":["create","rename","delete"],"failureHandling":"textOnlyTransactional…
> [11:46:14 PM] [General] [Info] Loaded 20000 package names from vscode-userdata:/c%3A/Users/ADULUSMAN/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/globalStorage/dart-code.dart-code/package_cache.json
> [11:46:14 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Error] << was unexpected at this time.

Dart Code extension: 3.85.20240327
Flutter extension: 3.85.20240301 (not activated)

App: Visual Studio Code
App Host: desktop
Version: win 1.87.2

Workspace type: Flutter (LSP)

Unexpectedly i rollback the flutter repository from my vs code then i cant use flutter camand
[image]

Answer (score 1):

first you have to check which channel you have updated.make sure its stable . otherwise reinstall.

[image]

then , check with path variable rightly configured using open .zprofile at users directory

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/x/{path}/flutter/bin"